Invalid Hook Call, How Can I Make It Work
I am trying to work with Redux. I have a select form for sorting data. I need to dispatch actions when onChange works but can't do it because I can't use it inside onChange event handler.
Form:
const onChange = (evnt) => {
  dispatch(setSort(evnt.target.value));
  dispatch(fetchProducts(dispatch));
};

...

<select
  onChange={onChange}
  className="border-[1px] p-4 bg-[#F9F9F9] text-"
>
  <option>Sort</option>
  ...
</select>

Actions:
export const setSort = (sort) => ({
  type: SET_SORT,
  payload: sort
});

export const fetchProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(setFetchState("FETCHING"));

  let categoryId = useSelector((store) => store.product.categoryId);
  let filter = useSelector((store) => store.product.filter);
  let sort = useSelector((store) => store.product.sort);

  let query = "/products";

  ...
}

I couldn't think anything about it

React hooks can only be called in React functions and custom React hooks, so trying to use and call the useSelector hook in the fetchProducts action creator is invalid. Luckily for you the thunk function is passed two arguments, the dispatch function for dispatching further actions and a getState function for accessing the current store value.
Update fetchProducts to use the passed getState function.
Example:
export const fetchProducts = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch(setFetchState("FETCHING"));

  const state = getState();

  const { categoryId, filter, sort } = state.product;

  let query = "/products";

  ...
};

You also don't need to pass dispatch to the action creator, the Thunk middleware handles passing dispatch to the action function that fetchProducts returns.
const onChange = (event) => {
  dispatch(setSort(event.target.value));
  dispatch(fetchProducts());
};

See Writing Thunks for further details.
